# How to set Post ID from context to an attribute in child block of Gutenberg Query Loop

Tags: hooks, block-editor

I have a custom Gutenberg block that is nested within a query loop block, and I want to save the post ID as an attribute on each instance of the block.

The block is an accordion component, so I planned to use the Post ID to distinguish from any other accordions on the page.

Here's a simplified version of the block's `edit.js`

```
const Edit = ( props ) => {
    const { attributes: { blockId }, context: { postId }, setAttributes } = props;

    useEffect( () => {
        setAttributes( { blockId: postId } );
    });

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <button data-disclosure-toggle={ blockId }>
                Accordion toggle button
            </button>
            <div data-disclosure-target={ blockId }>
                Accordion content
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Edit;
```

And here's a simplified save.js

```
const Save = ( props ) => {
    const { attributes: { blockId } } = props;
    
    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <button data-disclosure-toggle={ blockId }>
                Accordion toggle button
            </button>
            <div data-disclosure-target={ blockId }>
                Accordion content
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Save;
```

The issue I'm having is that while both `postId` and `blockID` are showing correctly in the Editor, on the front-end every `blockId` is being set to the same value; the ID of the first post in the loop.

I'm guessing this is to do with the render function firing multiple times, which I was trying to mitigate with `UseEffect`. For some reason it's not working in this instance.

Also, while typically I would wrap setAttributes in an if statement:

```
if ( !blockId ) {
    setAttributes( { blockId: postId } );
}
```

In this case, the `blockId` somehow already seems to be set to the `postId`, so `setAttributes` doesn't fire with the if statement present. I'm not sure why this is.

What's the best way to pull in the postId from context and set it to the blockId attribute so that it can be used on the front-end?

EDIT: As Tom points out in the comments below, using the Post ID might not be the best solution here. I really need any ID that is unique to the block in question. Initially I was using clientId, which works fine outside the Query Loop block, but within a Query Loop it always produces the same result every time.

Comment: are you sure this is even possible? Those "instances" aren't created until the user is viewing that block on the frontend, so you can't know the post ID in advance, otherwise there'd be no need for a query block. In the editor there is only one block, and your blocks edit component and save components _only_ run in the block editor, they do not run on the frontend when the page is generated

Comment: Instead, you should avoid this solution to your problem and ask about your original problem instead. What are you trying to do on the frontend that requires the post ID? That's a much easier and straightforward challenge to solve. Also please update your question with your save component and the details of what you're trying to achieve ( be specific avoid abstract/generic descriptions )

Comment: @TomJNowell It seemed possible, as when logging the output in the editor I can see the blockId is set to the postId, but later overwritten. This led me to assume it was an issue with setAttributes being rerun.

Comment: @TomJNowell You're right though - this may not be the best solution to the problem. The block is an accordion component which needs a unique ID so the toggle button knows what content area to target if there are multiple accordion blocks on a page. It doesn't necessarily have to be the Post ID, as long as the ID is unique to each block. I was initially using clientId, but that doesn't work when the block is nested in a query loop.

I'll update the initial question shortly with the extra info.

Comment: you could always assign an identifier at runtime to the HTML or with data attributes using JS before you attach your event handlers, but if it must have it added via the server, then it has to be done at frontend render time in PHP, it can't be done from the editor.

Comment: @TomJNowell Updated the original question - not sure if it changes anything. Sounds like I might have to use a PHP render template if not.

Comment: yup I think a PHP rendered template is unavoidable here if you want each instance of the block to be different